# Rails 4.2.0 app: delete link javascript stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, destroy, confirm

I have a Rails 4.2.0 app that has been running for several months now.

The app has link_to tags in various places using "delete" as the method and with a confirmation prompt.  These have been working correctly, with the alert popping up to confirm before the deletion and the request being routed to the destroy action in the controller as expected.

Today one of the app users asked me why the delete links don't work.  No confirmation alert is displayed, and the resulting request is a simple GET that is routed to the show action instead of destroy.  Although my users don't delete very often, I am certain that they were working originally.

The delete links no longer work in either development or live environments.  There are no javascript errors in the browser console either when loading the page containing the links or when clicking on a delete link.  The behavior is the same on Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

The mysterious part is that I have been making mainly code and database changes for months; I can't remember the last time I added a gem or ran bundle install or update.  Obviously something has to have changed to break the javascript, but I can't think what it could be.

So far, I have removed the rails jQuery and linked to one from Google API.  I have removed Turbolinks.  I have updated the jquery-rails gem from v. 4.0.3 to 4.2.1.  No luck.

In case anyone can suggest something to test or look at, here are some excerpts from my configuration and code (after reverting the above failed attempts):

Gemfile.lock:

```
jquery-rails (4.0.3)
jquery-turbolinks (2.1.0)
jquery-ui-rails (5.0.3)
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require_tree .
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb, inside the  tag:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Delete link tags look like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', item_order_path(@item, order), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: :button %>
```

In the rendered HTML they look like this:

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" class="button" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/items/1/orders/1">Delete</a>
```

Any ideas of what could be going on?

Comment: Which OS you are working on? If it is windows then try gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'

Comment: I am running the app either on Mac OS X 10.11 (development, using the WEBrick server) or CentOS 7 (production, using Apache and Passenger Phusion).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out what the problem was (and he was myself!).

I was going to delete the question in utter shame, but then I figured that somebody might benefit from seeing the way in which I tracked down the problem.

First, I sort of remembered that the last gem-related change was to add an autocomplete field to the app.  So I took out the line

```
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
```

from application.js.  Et voilà!  Delete links started working again.

I was about to self-righteously blame jquery-ui for being incompatible with Rails javascript when I noticed that removing that line was actually throwing an exception at the point in which my javascript was initializing the autocomplete field.  This sounded suspiciously like something in my app's javascript was interfering with the link javascript, which the exception was coincidentally preventing from being executed.

So I reverted the application.js file and renamed all my javascript assets so that the server would not recognize them.  Delete links were now working again.  Then I restored each of my javascript files one by one, testing the links after a page refresh.  Eventually the delete links stopped working after reintroducing one file: this file was a recent change.

The problem itself was that all my delete links are contained in tables, and to those tables I recently added click handlers to sort the rows.  My click handler for the table was stopping propagation on the click event, which was preventing the Rails handler for the delete links from kicking in.  I have not worked out the fix yet, but it will likely involve targeting the sorting event handler more carefully so that the delete links are not affected.